# how to show the NSData value in UIImage View while retrieving the database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uiimage, nsdata

Added the images as NSData in database successfully.  But while i'm retrieving back NSData to UIImage its not working.  The following codings that i used for retrieving the database any error please suggest me.[image]

Here i used primary key to fetch correct image presented in particular record:

```
-(void)ShowImagesinImageView{

    NSLog(@"Loaded in productlist");
    NSLog(@"Primary Key of Expenses ID=%@",primarykeyID);

    proID      = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSInteger proeditid = [primarykeyID integerValue];
    int len = 0;

    NSString *queryStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select image from selection_tbl where expenses_id=?"];
    Dataware *dbsql    = [[Dataware alloc] initDataware];
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStmt=[dbsql OpenSQL:[queryStr UTF8String]];

    Dataware *DB = [[Dataware alloc]initDataware];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt=[DB OpenSQL:[queryStr UTF8String]];
    if(sqlStmt != nil)
        while(sqlite3_step(sqlStmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            len = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 0);
            NSData *imagData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, 0) length: len];

            sqlite3_bind_int(stmt,1, (int)proeditid);

            UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imagData];
            imageView.image = img;

        }
    [dbsql CloseSQL];

    [tblview reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Please tell me what is the problem.

Comment: show error message also if you have.

Comment: @SumitGarg it doesn't shows the image in image view

Comment: Is imagData variable consiste NSData after this `NSData *imagData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, 0) length: len];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

```
NSString *queryStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select image from selection_tbl where expenses_id=%ld",(long)proeditid];

    Dataware *dbsql    = [[Dataware alloc] initDataware];
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStmt=[dbsql OpenSQL:[queryStr UTF8String]];

    if(sqlStmt != nil)
        while(sqlite3_step(sqlStmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSData *dataForCachedImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStmt, 0) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStmt, 0)];
            UIImage *img;
            img = [UIImage imageWithData:dataForCachedImage];
            imageView.image =img;
        }
    [dbsql CloseSQL];
    [tblview reloadData];
```

I guess so.

Answer (score 0):

you have used very complex way to fetch data from Database

used this one it is very easy to understand.

```
-(void)getListOfUnitsNameByCategory1{

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSInteger proeditid = [primarykeyID integerValue];

    int len = 0;

    NSString *queryString=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"select image from selection_tbl where expenses_id=%ld",(long)proeditid];

    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) <= SQLITE_ROW) {
            len = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0);
            NSData *imagData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0) length: len];

            UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imagData];
            imageView.image = img;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

       [tblview reloadData];

    }
}
```

Comment: Everything is fine one here but it showing only one error
~~~  
if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)  ~~~

Error is::  Use of undeclared identifier '_database'

Comment: Everything is fine on here but it showing only one error
~~~  
if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)  ~~~

Error is::  Use of undeclared identifier '_database'

Comment: `_database` is a variable of  `sqlite3 *` type, you also used this with some other name at the time of insertion.

Comment: I think ` Dataware *dbsql    = [[Dataware alloc] initDataware];` this is your sqlite3 type.